# For an inverting amplifier, Vin= 1V, R1= 5 ohms, Rf=10 ohms, frequency=100Hz. Why is output distorted

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

Can anyone explain how the low values of resistor are causing distortion in output.

Thanks

Comment: Consider there is a limit to the amount of current a device can output.

Comment: Your resistor values are so low that more current is required than the op-amp can drive to produce the voltages necessary across the resistors for your circuit to function as expected. You normally use at least 1K, and often 5K-20K. Sometimes even higher.

Comment: Which simulator is that?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Looks like Multisim GUI. aka: Electronic Workbench. That LM741 model seems OK (except for simulating smoke) - it is going hard into current limiting.

Comment: The UA709 opamp had no short-circuit protection. More modern opamps do have over-current protection.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone explain how the low values of resistor are causing
>   distortion in output.

In an ideal op-amp it won't distort but, in a real op-amp (such as the 741) it cannot deal with both input and feedback resistor having such low values and obvious distortion is guaranteed. The op-amp is trying to sustain the Vin- point at ground level and that means driving far too much current through the 10 ohm resistor.

Try using 5 k and 10 k resistors instead and note the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Some simulators ignore actual characteristics of which each has many for input, output: V,I,f, phase, GBW, Vcm-max, Vdif-max, current limit, slew rate, to name just a few.

Since a '741 is current-limited, it cannot possibly drive 10 ohms at large 1V swings, so the model assumptions are invalid, so you may expect queer results.